# F2, F3, F4, 3, E keys stopped working in dell inspiron 3505

Tags: keyboard, dell-inspiron

The above mentioned keys stopped working on its own. It works with external keyboard. It had happened once before as well but it started working on its own after 3-4 months. But the same issue came again. Before it stopped working, the keys were not responding well but now its is not working completely.

Comment: Replace the built-in keyboard.

Comment: & check your battery is not swelling

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser. Do they work with the `Fn` key is pressed with them?

Comment: No they dont work when pressed with Fn as well

Comment: Keys not working in diagonal stripes indicates PCB damage. If the battery swells, that can a) break it & b) show up more depending on the weather/temperature.